# How can I add a value to a new column based on a value existing in my dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

[Image of how my dataframe looks at the minute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS6Nr.jpg)

I am trying to put a new column into my dataframe called "council" which will be based upon the Town field. So for example, if the `Town == Belfast`, I want the new column council to hold the value Belfast. However a note to make is, some of these council values are not the same as the town. Another example may be, the town could be Clogher and I want to put in the council value Fermanagh. I am very new to python and would really appreciate any help. If you need any more information that I have left out please ask. (So far I have only tried this for the council area Belfast)

What I want to do is loop over every row in my data frame and check the "Town" Column. If the Town column is equal to "Belfast" Then I would like to input the value "Belfast" into a new Column called "Council."

```
count = 0
for index, row in PsniYear1617Cleaned.iterrows():
     grabtown = PsniYear1617Cleaned["Town"]
    for value in grabtown: 
        if value["Town"][0] == "Belfast":
            PsniYear1617Cleaned.set_value(index, 'Council', value["Belfast"])
            count = count + 1
```

`TypeError

Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-122-31f11c973fc5> in <module>()
      3     grabtown = PsniYear1617Cleaned["Town"]
      4     for value in grabtown:
----> 5         if value["Town"][0] == "Belfast":
      6             PsniYear1617Cleaned.set_value(index, 'Council', value["Belfast"])
      7             count = count + 1`

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: do you mean `dataframe` in `pandas` ?

Comment: I apologise, yes I'm using pandas

Comment: all code make no sense - `pandas` can works with data without `for` loops

Comment: you mean to say u need a new column `council` which should be equal to `town`

Comment: You do not need to loop through each row. Try this: `df['Council']=np.where(df.Town=='Belfast', 'Belfast', df.Town)`. Or I guess you just need the Council column to be equal to Town. So `df['Council']=df['Town']`

Comment: @armark not always equal. For example, if the value in town is "Enniskillen." I'd like to be able to have the council value of this row as "Fermanagh."

Comment: then, define all the conditions of what Council must be if town is what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need create `dictionary` for maping by all possible `town`s with different `council` and then use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
d = {'Enniskillen':'Fermanagh', 
     'Clogher':'Fermanagh', 
      'town1':'council1',
      ...}

PsniYear1617Cleaned['council'] = PsniYear1617Cleaned['Town'].replace(d)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for and was the easiest solution for me. Perfect answer, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
PsniYear1617Cleaned[:,'council'] = PsniYear1617Cleaned['Town'].apply(lambda x: TOWN_MAP[x])
```

In this case you have a town map which stores all the corresponding councils for the given town and the lambda will do the rest.